# React - Open Modal Dialog (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

First, I'm almost new to `reactjs`. I want to create a simple editing mask for getting deeper into `reactjs`. 
What is the "Best Practice" for this situation?

I'm having a page, where you can simply add, change or delete a company entry.
What I want to achieve is, to open a modal dialog window, when I click on a company entry. In the modal dialog window then, the user can modify or delete the entry.

First I created a `CompanyList` component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Company from './Company';

class CompanyList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            search: '',
            companies: props.companies
        };
    }

    updateSearch(event) {
        this.setState({ search: event.target.value.substr(0,20) })
    }

    addCompany(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      let nummer = this.refs.nummer.value;
      let bezeichnung = this.refs.bezeichnung.value;
      let id = Math.floor((Math.random()*100) + 1);
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          context:this,
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          url: "../data/post/json/companies",
          data: ({ 
              _token : window.Laravel.csrfToken,
              nummer: nummer,
              bezeichnung : bezeichnung,
          }),
          success: function (data) {
            id = data.Nummer;
            this.setState({
              companies: this.state.companies.concat({id, nummer, bezeichnung})
            })
            this.refs.bezeichnung.value = '';
            this.refs.nummer.value = '';
          }
      });
    }

    render() {
      let filteredCompanies = this.state.companies.filter(
        (company) => {
          return company.bezeichnung.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        }
      );
        return (
        <div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Search</div>
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
              <div className="form-group">
                <input className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.search} placeholder="Search" onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <form onSubmit={this.addCompany.bind(this)}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Create new entry</div>
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input className="form-control" type="text" ref="nummer" placeholder="New company no." required />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <input className="form-control" type="text" ref="bezeichnung" placeholder="New company name" required />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Add new company</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
              <ul>
              { 
                filteredCompanies.map((company)=> {
                  return (
                    <div>
                      <Company company={company} key={company.id} />
                    </div>
                  );
                })
              }
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CompanyList
```

The `Company` component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Company extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            company: props.company,
            onClick: props.onClick
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <li>
                    <div className="cursorPointer" >
                        {this.props.company.nummer} {this.props.company.bezeichnung} 
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Company
```

My issue is now, how and where to implement the modal dialog? 
Is it best practice to create an own component for it e.g. `CompanyOptions`? Should it be part of `Company` or better one component added in `CompanyList`? But then, how to pass the current `Company` to the modal dialog. 
Sorry, if I'm asking too many questions. But I want to find out how it is recommended in `reactjs`.

**UPDATE**

Now I've created an own component for it.

This component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class CompanyOptions extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            company: props.company,
            css: props.css,
            onClick: props.onClick
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>      
              <div className={this.state.css} tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <h4 className="modal-title">Company entry "{this.state.company.bezeichnung}"</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                      <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CompanyOptions
```

In the `Company` component I render it this way:

```
render() {

return (
    <div>
        <li>
            <div className="cursorPointer" onClick={this.toggleOptionFields.bind(this)}>
                {this.props.company.nummer} {this.props.company.bezeichnung} 
            </div>
            <CompanyOptions company={this.state.currentCompany} css={this.state.optionFieldsCss} />
...
```

I've created a state and a method for the click event:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        company: props.company,
        onClick: props.onClick,
        editFieldsCss: "displayNone",
        optionFieldsCss: "modal fade",
        currentCompany: props.company,
    };
}
```

and the method:

```
toggleOptionFields() {
    var css = (this.state.optionFieldsCss === "modal fade in displayBlock") ? "modal fade" : "modal fade in displayBlock";
    this.setState({
        "optionFieldsCss":css,
        currentCompany: this.company
    });
}
```

But when I click on the company the css in the component call is updated. But not in the component itself:

[image]

Why? Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a new component for a modal. This way it would be reusable.

Then you can include it where you need it and you can send all company info via props to that modal.

Add an state property `showModal` and set it to `false`. Then `onClick` event change `showModal` to `true`. Then in your `render` method you can check `if(this.state.showModal)` and then show modal.

Your state :

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       showModal: false,
       currentCompanyName: "",
       currentCompanyNumber: ""
   }
}
```

Then `onClick` event:

```
handleClick(currentCompanyName, currentCompanyNumber){
   this.setState({
       showModal: true,
       currentCompanyName: currentCompanyName,
       currentCompanyNumber: currentCompanyNumber
   })
}
```

And then in your render:

```
render(){
    if(this.state.showModal)
       return <MyModal companyName={this.state.currentCompanyName} companyNumber={this.state.currentCompanyNumber} />

    return (
       //Rest of the code
    )

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but it actually did not work well. Please see my updated post.

Comment: @dns_nx And if you use `this.props.css` instead of `this.state.css` in your `CompanyOptions` modal?